# SDL2 events don't work in C

Tags: c, events, gcc, sdl

I am trying to use SDL2 in C language compiled with GCC but the events don't work, for example, I can't close the window with SDL_QUIT.
Is anything wrong on the code, please ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout,"Échec\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window* windowImg = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderImg = NULL;
    int quit = 0;
    SDL_Event e;

    windowImg = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 400, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    renderImg = SDL_CreateRenderer(windowImg, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(windowImg);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Workin' fine (i.e., hitting the `SDL_QUIT` logic & exiting) on Win7 w/VS2012 when I click the close-window ("X") button.  How are you attempting to generate a `SDL_QUIT` event?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I forgot to link libraries in the build options > linker options :
-lSDL2main -lSDL2